# Neo4j Cypher Conditionally Create Relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following situation in Neo4j.

I have two nodes that I know exist: `(x:X)` and `(y:Y)`.

If the relationship `(x)-[:A]->(z:Z)` exists, then I want to create the relationship `(y)-[:B]->(z)`. Otherwise, I want to do nothing (i.e., no relationship should be created). How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

First, find the matching nodes. Then create relationships between them.

```
MATCH (x)-[:A]->(z:Z), (y:Y)
MERGE (y)-[:B]->(z)
```

You can also specify any necessary matching conditions, such as.

```
MATCH (x)-[:A]->(z:Z), (y:Y)
WHERE z.name = "foo"
AND y.type = "bar"
MERGE (y)-[:B]->(z)
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `Failed to create relationship   UNNAMED358, node   z@304 is missing.`

Comment: And how about if you replace the `CREATE` by `MERGE` keyword?